# .NET MAUI Dynamic Tab page

Tags: .net-maui, tabbedpage

I am having issue to implement dynamic tab page in .NET MAUI project. Can we add tabs into Navigation page at runtime to open Webpage. I am trying to implement functionality model like Chrome or Edge to open web URLs in separate tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we add tabs into Navigation page at runtime to open Webpage

What does the webpage mean? At first, if you want to add a new tab into the TabbedPage when the user operates in the child page, you can use the the following code in the child page:

```
var tabbedpage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
tabbedpage.Children.Add(new ChildPage());
```

And then if the ChildPage just have a webview in it and you want to add a new tab when the webview navigates to a new url. You can add a `Navigating` event to the webview and pass the url to the child page.

**Update**

You can create a construction method which has a parameter for the ChildPage, such as:

```
public ChildPage(string url)
{
   //use the url here
}
```

Comment: Hi Zhang, I need to create child pages at runtime to open different URLs in each created child page.

Comment: The code above shows how to create child pages at runtime. @GajendraSingh

Comment: Thank you @Liyun Zhang - MSFT - This worked. Appreciate your help!!